# JS/XSS: When assigning user-provided strings to variables; is it enough to replace <,>, and string delimiter?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

If a server-side script generates the following output:

```
<script>
var a = 'text1';
var b = 'text2';
var c = 'text3';
</script>
```

, and the values (in this example "text1", "text2" and "text3") are user supplied (via HTTP GET/POST), is it enough to remove < and > from the input and to replace

'

with

```
' + "'" + '
```

in order to be safe from XSS? (This is my main question)

I'm particularly worried about the backslash not being escaped because an attacker could unescape the trailing '. Could that be a potential problem in this context? If the variable assignments were **not** separated by line breaks, an attacker could supply the values

```
text1
text2\
;alert(1);//
```

and end up with working JS code like

```
<script>
var a = 'text1'; var b = 'text2\'; var c = ';alert(1);//text3';
</script>
```

But since there **are** line breaks that shouldn't be a problem either. Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

It would be more secure to JSON encode your data, instead of rolling your own Javascript encoding function. When dealing with web application security, rolling your own is almost always not the answer. A JSON representation would handle the quotes and backslashes and any other special characters.

Most server side languages have a JSON module. Some also have a function specifically for what  you're doing such as [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx) for the .NET framework.

If you were to roll your own, then it would be better to replace the characters for example like `"` to `\x22`, instead of changing single quotes or removing them. Also consider there is a multitude of creative XSS attacks that you'd need to defend against.

The end result, whatever method you use, is your data should remain intact when presented to the user. For example it's no good having `O"Neil` if someone's name is `O'Neil`.

Comment: +1 but note that characters U+2028 and U+2029 are invalid in string literals in JavaScript but not in JSON, and some JSON encoders don't `\u`-escape them. This is not generally exploitable because you end up with a syntax error, but it's a bit bad. Another alternative is to include all data you are passing to JavaScript in HTML attributes in the DOM (eg in `data-` attributes), where you can use the same normal HTML encoding as everywhere else. Then read them from JavaScript using `getAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I agree more characters should be encoded, but since what I've described above is already live, I can't rebuild or change it unless there's a "tangible" problem.

The potential problem I see is that it's possible to unescape the trailing string delimiter ('), but apparently there's no way to exploit this code other than rendering the script/page unusable, e.g. no XSS/code injection is possible?

Comment: @kazhtaco yes, you would need to escape, remove or encode the backslashes to prevent that. Not sure if there's an exploit for that but it's definitely needs to be prevented.

Comment: @bobince agreed, HTML attributes with the usual encoding would work too.